# How to pull div attributes with BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull this data (lat and lng):

```
<div class="location"
    lat="1234"
    lng="5678"
>
```

This is giving me nothing:

```
print (soup.find_all("div", { "class" : "location"}))
```

My eventual goal is to store these values in a dictionary. Thanks.

Comment: Well you need to share the url  if it is not working. The content may be dynamically rendered so not in the source returned but only you know what you are scraping.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *dictionary like-access to element attribute* in BeautifulSoup:

```
locations = [{'lat': location['lat'], 'lng': location['lng']}
             for location in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "location"})]
```

If there is a single location, use `find()` instead:

```
location = soup.find("div", {"class": "location"})
print({'lat': location['lat'], 'lng': location['lng']})
```

> This is giving me nothing

This is though a separate problem. You might just not have this element in the parsed HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Your current `print` is returning a *list* of results:

```
[<div class="location" lat="1234" lng="5678"></div>]
```

You can access these by iterating through each result:

```
for r in results:
    print(r['lat'], r['lng'])
```

---

A full example, with two `div` elements, looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="location"
    lat="1234"
    lng="5678"
>
<div class="location"
    lat="9101"
    lng="1213"
>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all("div", { "class" : "location"})
for r in results:
    print(r['lat'], r['lng'])
```

This prints out two results:

```
('1234', '5678')
('9101', '1213')
```

Answer (score 0):

From BeautifulSoup docs you might be using find_all() wrong.
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments

Try:

```
print (soup.find_all("div",class_="location"))
```

or

```
print (soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class": "location"}))
```